# How to check if DB table exists?

Tags: api, mysql

Is there a built-in way to check to see if a DB table exists via PHP? I'd like to add that to my API call and create the table if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specific CiviCRM function (but all the ways in the other answers will be just as good :-)):

```
CRM_Core_DAO::checkTableExists($tableName)
```

This function will return TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing PHP in a CiviCRM extension - you can add a /sql/install.sql file in which you can execute MySQL commands like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Answer (score 2):

[CRM_Queue_BAO_QueueItem:: findCreateTable()](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Queue/BAO/QueueItem.php#L50) contains an example of how CiviCRM does this, and the presence of this suggested that no "canned" method might exist already.

```
$checkTableSql = "show tables like 'civicrm_queue_item'";
$foundName = CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery($checkTableSql);
if ($foundName == 'civicrm_queue_item') {
  return TRUE;
}
```

But I was wrong, see ErikH's answer: [`CRM_Core_DAO::checkTableExists()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/DAO.php#L958)!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the table, you could use MySQL via command line:

Log into MySQL using terminal and then execute a command:

`mysql -u [username] -p`

mysql> `show tables like "test1";`

If it exists, you will get an output such as:

```
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_test (test1) |
+------------------------+
| test1                  |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

https://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-if-mysql-table-exists/

Comment: I need to do it from my PHP script. I could probably execute that query using CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery()